# App Verification for OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications

Tags: search, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

### Is the Google application verification required for Server to Server OAuth 2.0?

We are working on an application that writes to a Google Sensitive scope. We have searched the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=en_US) for OAuth 2.0 regarding Server to Server Applications and cannot determine is the application verification is required. The only sort of definitive answer is in this snippet from the Server to Server OAuth docs

> Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account,
> so users aren't directly involved.

Our application is hosted within a sub-government environment that blocks traffic originating from the outside. We have successfully demonstrated the read and write to the "user public" sensitive scope (because the OAUTH traffic is initiated from the inside) with Google API Client Library for JavaScript.

But, we are not able to verify the application by [DNS or other methods](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?authuser=1) using Oauth2 public method. We believe this is because for each verification method, Google servers need access to the internal (government) environment. We are also not allowed to use the internal "private" method.

Below is a simplistic drawing of a user being posed with an application verification dialog when trying to use the sensitive scope. The drawing also shows that the verification for the public method not being successful because it's blocked from the Government firewall(s)

[image]

Comment: Why would some downvote this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the OAuth Flow that you have described.

For Google Service to Service authorization, use a Service Account and not a User Account. For internal services use Token Based Authentication (one of many methods).

[Google Authentication Overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/)
[Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started)

> But, we are not able to verify the application by DNS or other methods
>   using Oauth2 public method. We believe this is because for each
>   verification method, Google servers need access to the internal
>   (government) environment. We are also not allowed to use the internal
>   "private" method.

What application are you referring to? Google servers do not access your internal servers. When using the User type of OAuth Flow, Google verifies the callback URL for your service. This means that Google needs to verify that you own/control the domain name. Since this is an internal private domain, this is not possible. However, you are using the wrong type of OAuth Flow so worrying about this is the wrong direction to take.

For an internal server to server authorization, there are many methods. Probably the best and easiest is to emulate how OAuth does it. Create a signed JWT with a certificate private key on one server and verify the signed JWT using the public key on the other service. You have now verified that the request is valid from a known source. Next embed in the JWT the identity, permissions/roles, etc. that you want to implement/control. The other side verifies that the permissions requested have been granted for the identity.

[Introduction to JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction/)
[Token Based Authentication Made Easy](https://auth0.com/learn/token-based-authentication-made-easy/)

Answer (score -2):

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, furthermore it is regarding Google and the answer involves instagram.

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

Comment: curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \

Comment: يصل التصويت
-2
أسفل التصويت
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token